Examples of physical systems where total energy is conserved but total angular momentum/total linear momentum are not conserved?
I came across  this question:
$H=\frac{1}{2}{m_1v_1}^2+\frac{1}{2}{m_2v_2}^2+\frac{C}{(\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2})^2}\hat{z}.(\vec{r_1} \times\vec{r_2} )$
This is a hamiltonian of a two particle system where symbols have their usual meanings and $C$ is a constant. Here total energy should be conserved as there is no explicit time dependence of the hamiltonian. I am unable to understand the potential energy term physically and how it relates to angular momentum. The question has four options out of which the correct option says that only the total energy and the $\hat{z}$ component of the angular momentum is conserved. I can't think of an isolated system that satisfies this condition. Though I could somewhat understand an example given to me as two charged particles in a magnetic field where the magnetic field can exert a torque on the system making the angular momentum to be non conserved. But, I can't get how a particular component of the angular momentum might be conserved. Could someone give an example or elaborate on this example? Is it possible for an isolated two particle system not interacting with anything but only with themselves to achieve such conditions?

the unit of C is $~[N,m]~$ which is the unit of torque. hence $~C,\hat z=\frac {d,\vec L}{dt}=\tau~$ the z component of the angular momentum

Any non-central potential - say a particle moving in the field of two fixed attractive centers - will not conserve angular momentum but will conserve energy…

Consider a spinning top in perfect precession, no nutation. Gravity produces torque in horizontal plane, so vertical component of angular momentum is constant in time.
